# What Arduino board with WiFi should I choose

Tags: shields, wifi, arduino-yun

I want to implement an Arduino module with some sensors and send the info through WiFi to a server. I'm looking for the best board or component combination to make this. What is the best board or solution you would use in my case? Maybe Arduino Yun or Intel Edison Kit for Arduino...¿?

I've developed a sensor module with Redbear Blend board which use Bluetooth to communicate with an Android app to send sensor data, but now looking for WiFi connection.

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm new in this Arduino world. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend ESP8266 (model 07) based board. 
[image: ESP8266 model 07]

- Can be programmed the same way as other Arduinos
- Cheap
- Enough storage for code
- Fairly low power
- Large community (more code examples and better library support)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm checking it right now and it seems just what i was looking 4 ;)